# Enviar archivo XML por CURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

Estoy intentando enviar un archivo XML por CURL pero me da el siguiente error:

> {"Message":"Incorrect call: Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided.
> It does not have a content-type header value. 'HttpContent' instances
> must have a content-type header starting with
> 'multipart/'.\r\nParameter name: content"}

Que me puede estar faltando?

Este es mi codigo:

```php
$header = array(
    "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($datos_fact_elect['usuario'].':'.$datos_fact_elect['clave']),
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;",
);

if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.5+
    $cFile = curl_file_create("./test.xml");
} else {
    $cFile = '@' . realpath("./test.xml");
}
$post = array('Archivo' => $cFile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_soap.'Comprobante/ComprimirComprobante');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: En `$header` agrega también esto: `"Content-Type: application/xml",`

Comment: @A. Cedano ya lo agregué pero aun persiste el error

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($header);` y qué muestra un `var_dump($post);`
?

Comment: @A.Cedano VAR_DUMP del HEADER: array(2) { [0]=> string(129) "Authorization: Basic Y3pCbE1YSXdkakZwTUdNeGFUQnZNWE13Y3pGaE1IUXhKakJUTVVFd1ZERT06TVRBM01URXdOREU0TURreE9EQXlNVEl3TmpFd01EQXhNVEE9" [1]=> string(34) "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" }

Comment: @A.Cedano VAR_DUMP del POST: array(1) { ["Archivo"]=> object(CURLFile)#11 (3) { ["name"]=> string(10) "./test.xml" ["mime"]=> string(0) "" ["postname"]=> string(0) "" } }

Comment: A ver, en el `var_dump` de `$header` no veo el `"Content-Type: application/xml"` y es extraño que en el otro `var_dump` no haya el MIME type `application/xml`. Puede ser porque no lo indicaste en el header, o porque no estás creando un `.xml` correcto y por eso no identifica el tipo MIME. Por favor, pon el Content-Type en `$header` como te indiqué en un anterior comentario y prueba de nuevo. Si sigue fallando habrá que ver si realmente se crea un `.xml` válido.